# Problem with inserting records and the for loop. Only a few records are saved in the database, not all of them

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, selenium, sqlite

After a successful scraping (only and exclusively for study and personal purposes), I try to insert the records into a database. But I have a problem:

not all records are inserted in the database table, but only one (1) for each for loop. I would like to enter the entire list of 20 clubs into the table, but only 1 record is saved and not 20. In my case, 40 records should be entered (20 for Serie A and 20 for Serie B), but only 2 are entered in database. Instead the scrape in the console happens successfully and shows everything

I know what the error is and where I am wrong (needless to comment on the error), but I can't solve it. Can you show me how to solve please? I'm just starting out with Python, if you can please show me the code, otherwise I probably wouldn't understand. Thank

```
#SCRAPING
#SerieA
driver.minimize_window()
driver.get("url")
time.sleep(20)

for SerieA in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href^='/squadra'][class^='tableCellParticipant__name']"):
    SerieA_text = SerieA.text
    print(SerieA_text)
driver.close

#SerieB
driver.minimize_window()     
driver.get("url")
time.sleep(15)

for SerieB in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href^='/squadra'][class^='tableCellParticipant__name']"):
    SerieB_text = SerieB.text
    print(SerieB_text)
driver.close


#INSERT IN DATABASE
con = sqlite3.connect('DATABASE.db')
cursor = con.cursor()
records_added_Risultati = 0
    
Values = ((SerieA_text,), (SerieB_text,))
sqlite_insert_query = 'INSERT INTO Squadre_Campionato (Nome_Squadra) VALUES (?);'
count = cursor.executemany(sqlite_insert_query, Values)
con.commit()
    
print("Record inserted successfully ", cursor.rowcount)
records_added_Risultati = records_added_Risultati + 1
cursor.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Values` argument that you are passing into the `executemany` operator has just two elements:

```
Values = ((SerieA_text,), (SerieB_text,))
```

See the following link for an example of how to use executemany:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html

The second argument should be a list of all rows that need to be inserted into the table.

The code should start by initializing `Values` to an empty list `[]`, and then in a `for` loop insert tuples that you are extracting

```
#SCRAPING
#SerieA
Values = []

driver.minimize_window()
driver.get("url")

for SerieA in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href^='/squadra'][class^='tableCellParticipant__name']"):
    SerieA_text = SerieA.text
    print(SerieA_text)
    Values.append(tuple([SerieA_text]))
driver.close

#SerieB
driver.minimize_window()     
driver.get("url")
time.sleep(15)

for SerieB in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href^='/squadra'][class^='tableCellParticipant__name']"):
    SerieB_text = SerieB.text
    print(SerieB_text)
    Values.append(tuple([SerieB_text]))
driver.close

for i in range(len(Values)):
    print(Values[i])

#INSERT IN DATABASE
con = sqlite3.connect('DATABASE.db')
cursor = con.cursor()
records_added_Risultati = 0

sqlite_insert_query = 'INSERT INTO Squadre_Campionato (Nome_Squadra) VALUES (?);'
count = cursor.executemany(sqlite_insert_query, Values)
con.commit()

print("Record inserted successfully ", cursor.rowcount)
records_added_Risultati = records_added_Risultati + 1
cursor.close()
```

Comment: However, the scraping is successful, all the lines are printed in the console. Could you help me by showing me the code to solve the problem? I have read your kind response and have read the suggested link. Theoretically I understand, but in practice I don't know how to solve. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like the scraping is successful and you are printing the lines to the console. But you are not constructing the Values argument so that it contains all 40 rows to be inserted into the Squadre_Campionato table.

See the edited code above.

Comment: So do I have to delete your old SerieA_list = [] and SerieB_list = [] suggested earlier? Should I only use Values = []? Values = [] only once? Or Values = [] for each SerieA and SerieB? I tried the code you wrote to me earlier, but the scraping records were not printed in the python console either

Comment: I tested your new code. I am getting this error Values.append (tuple [SerieB_text]) TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable. I think it's a simple typo, because the brackets are different from SerieA Values.append. However I corrected the brackets: the scraping starts again in the console, but in the database the records still do not insert. Still entering 2 records and not 40. Can you review your code please? There is something wrong. Thanks

Comment: Yes Values.append(tuple([SerieB_text])) is correct. 

Can you try print(len(Values)) before the insert statement.

Comment: I tried print (len (Values)). The result is 2. So there is a problem :'(

Comment: Can you send the result of the edited code. Printing the elements of Values instead of len(Values).

Comment: If I understand what you are saying, here it is. Hope you can help me. I've been going crazy for days. Yet it is quite a simple thing. Thanks
SERIE A:
Napoli,
Milan
Inter
Roma
Lazio
Atalanta
Juventus
Bologna
Fiorentina
Empoli
Torino
Sassuolo
Udinese
Sampdoria
Verona
Venezia
Spezia
Cagliari
Genoa
Salernitana
 
SERIE B:
Pisa
Brescia
Benevento
Lecce
Cremonese
Frosinone
Perugia
Ascoli
Ternana
Reggina
Monza
Cittadella
Cosenza
Parma
Spal
Como
Crotone
Alessandria
L.R. Vicenza
Pordenone
 
 
2
Record inserted successfully  2

Comment: Yes, I understand that Serie A and Serie B each have 20 records. However, need to determine why Values is not being generated correctly. 

Please see the code for printing the elements of Values list. What does it print to the console?

Comment: On the console it prints exactly 40 names. Then the 2 of len you made me insert and finally Record inserted successfully 2. Nothing else. Do you know how I can modify the code to insert the 40 records in the database? Thanks

Comment: Instead of print(len(Values)), print the elements in Values. 
`for i in range(len(Values)):
    print(Values[i])`

Comment: I noticed that you have deleted Values ​​= ((SerieA_text,), (SerieB_text,)). Perhaps this was the problem. If I DO NOT delete it, thanks to for i in range etc etc, I get ('Salernitana',) ('Pordenone',). Only these 2. If I delete it, thanks to for i in range etc etc, it seems to get all the elements in the console (in addition to the ones that were already printed previously) and "Record inserted successfully  40". So the solution would be the code you wrote without for i in range etc etc? Can you explain to me what Values ​​= [] means? Because? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you have to delete `Values ​​= ((SerieA_text,), (SerieB_text,))`.  `Values ​​= []` means you are initializing to an empty list, and then inserting each of the 40 elements from SerieA and SerieB into the empty list, and then passing that as argument to executemany().

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I vote you

Comment: Excuse me. Considering you are good at scraping, could you help me with this new question please? Thanks 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69789261/problem-in-multiple-scraping-and-creating-a-database-record-it-doesnt-scrape-w

Comment: For privacy and security reasons can you remove the two links from your answer please? Maybe replace it with the word "link" or whatever you want. Sorry for the request. Also the link where you wrote "you are extracting from". I thank you in advance. P.S: I removed the green check from the answer just to write to you, then I will put it again after you have given me the confirmation that the link has been removed, so that in the meantime we can continue writing. Thanks

Comment: Excuse me again, but it's important: can you also remove the "that you are extracting from" piece (and its related link) please? I would like to remove it for privacy reasons. It's important.  I removed the green tick to let you make the change. Then I'll put it back right away. Thanks

Comment: @heovan1999 you should know that StackOverflow keeps the history of each question and answer: you can click on the `edited <date>` link and see the whole history. If these URLs really should have been kept private, your only option is to actually delete your question, however unfortunate that may be.

Comment: @joanis  I know there is a history. I tried to delete the question, but it doesn't delete. My question was for study purposes only. I deleted the link in my question. I'm simply asking you to remove a url in a response. Question and answer, without url, will still be useful to Stack Overflow readers for study purposes. Thanks

Comment: @heovan1999 Well, the edit you suggested yourself has been approved, so if that's good enough your privacy requirements, then all is well.